# Exercise 3.27 of Rudin's Functional Analysis - Missing Hypothesis

Tags: functional-analysis

Exercise 3.27 of Walter Rudin's Functional Analysis states,

> Suppose $\{\alpha_i\}$ is a bounded set of distinct complex numbers, $f(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty c_n z^n$ is an entire function with every $c_n \neq 0$, and $g_i(z) = f(\alpha_iz)$. Prove that the vector space generated by the functions $g_i$ is dense in the Frechet space $H(\mathbf{C})$ defined in Section 1.45.

$H(\mathbf{C})$ is topologized by taking the sup norm on a sequence of compact subsets of $\mathbf{C}$, so that their union is $\mathbf{C}$ and that $K_n$ is contained in the interior of $K_{n + 1}$.
The hypothesis of $\{\alpha_i\}$ is clearly not strong enough, because if $\{\alpha_i\}$ is finite, then we have a finite dimensional generated subspace, which is closed, so obviously cannot be dense.
I'd like to know if this is an established theorem so that $\{\alpha_i\}$ has a "natural" hypothesis, or if there is a correction somewhere, or if the question has an implicit hypothesis, or if I'm misunderstanding this question.

Comment: If $\alpha_i$'s are distinct how can $\{\alpha_i\}$ be a finite set?

Comment: There is nothing saying that the indices are infinite or finite. If it is possible to prove this theorem by assuming the set's cardinality, I'd like to know.

Comment: I think Rudin was taking the index set to be  $\mathbb N$.

Comment: thanks, I'll try solving it using that hypothesis